# Why printing a string show junk

Tags: c, initialization

Hello I am new to C and I am trying to print a string that i set by my self but it prints junk.

I know `id[4]` is `'\0'` so i did not set it.

```
int main(){
    char id[5];
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    id[0]=1;id[1]=2;id[2]=3;id[3]=4;
    printf("You entered the string %s\n",id); 
}
```

Comment: The string prints junk because you put junk characters into it. Neither of the four character codes corresponds to a printable character. On top of that `id[4]` is not zero, it's junk.

Comment: What do you *expect* to be printed?  Are you aware that `1` (for example) is not at all the same thing as `'1'`?

Comment: You should set id[4]='\0'. Your array is not "automatically terminated"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *I know `id[4]` is `'\0'`*

Well, you're wrong.

`id` being an automatic local variable, unless initialized explicitly, it contains indeterminate value. So, you cannot be sure of any value, let alone `'\0'`.

Quoting `C11`, §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [....]

However, if you initialize it like

```
 char id[5] = {0};
```

then, by rule of initialization, all the elements are 0-initialized and you can then rely on the null-termination.